# No Language in User File Template in ReSharper

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

I am using ReSharper 5.1.

I have created a User File Template called Singleton.

But it shows my template as folded into No Language section in ReSharper template collection:

http://img839.imageshack.us/img839/6585/resharpernolang.png

How do I set it to be in C# section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your Singleton template.  In the editor you will see a line that says "Available in" and a hyperlink.  The default is "Everywhere" I think.  If you click that blue link, you will get a "Template Option" dialog.  You can choose "Only in Projects for Language:" and choose one of the C# options.  That will list it in the C# language under your user templates.

Comment: Yep, but I am sure I have tried it before. The trick is to click the save button after you change Everywhere to C# projects several times, so it would save for sure.